# MDX exclude from level of hierarchy

Tags: mdx, sql-server-2016, ssas-tabular

I have a Geography hierarchy made this way:

- level 1: Continent
- level 2: Area
- level 3: City

I have to extract data of all distinct continents, but I have to exclude a specific city from one continent.
I cannot use neither WHERE clause nor nested FROM to filter it.
I tried many solutions such as EXCEPT, FILTER and "-" functions but none worked.

Here's an example of one of my wrong attempts, which extracts data but doesn't exclude the city I don't want:

```
Except( 
       [Zone].[GeographyHierarchy].[Continent].ALLMEMBERS,
    { 
            Descendants( 
                 [Zone].[GeographyHierarchy].[Continent].&[ContinentIWant].&[AreaIWant].&[CityIDontWant]
              , [Zone].[GeographyHierarchy].[Continent], SELF_AND_BEFORE ) } 
    )
```

Can anybody help to find a working solution?
Thank you all.

**EDIT**:

I think there's no solution by working on the highest level of the hierarchy, so I started filtering on the lowest level (City):

```
Except( [Zone].[GeographyHierarchy].[City].ALLMEMBERS,
        { [Zone].[GeographyHierarchy].[Continent].&[ContinentIWant].&[AreaIWant].&[CityIDontWant] } )
```

In this way I have all the distinct cities I Want, but I should now aggregate them on the higher level Continent.

Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Continent isn’t a descendent but also doing except on continent can only exclude whole continents

Comment: Hi @whytheq, thanx for your reply. I edited the question, trying another solution, do you have any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not to use a `WHERE` clause then you’ll need to create a new calculated member for the continent with the exclusion

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Zone].[GeographyHierarchy].[ALL].[ContinentIWant_exclX] AS
    [Zone].[GeographyHierarchy].[Continent].&[ContinentIWant]
    - [Zone].[GeographyHierarchy].[Continent].&[ContinentIWant].&[AreaIWant].&[CityIDontWant]  
SET [Continents] AS
     EXCEPT(
       [Zone].[GeographyHierarchy].[Continent].MEMBERS,
       [Zone].[GeographyHierarchy].[Continent].&[ContinentIWant]
     )
    +
     [Zone].[GeographyHierarchy].[ALL].[ContinentIWant_exclX]
...
```

Not ideal but without the possibility of using the WHERE clause things become tricky